# Folder icons gone, top right icons not theming

Tags: gnome, icons, gui

I'm new to ubuntu. I know some UNIX commands and can work my way around in a terminal, but this is driving me nuts. I am using 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit. I have reset unity, compiz, and --reset-unity (or whatever that command is). I have changed the theme in System Settings. Nothing has worked. I have screenshots uploaded to imgur. Any help would be appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DG5T.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHg4t.png

Answer (score 0):

Re install the ubuntu-desktop package with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

This should clear up the issue.

Comment: Didn't fix the problem. Same issue as before.